# Android Studio Printing EditText returns null

Tags: java, android

I've created a simple application where the user inputs their name and score which should be an integer only and then by clicking the button, it should print the data from those two EditText box's into the log. The issue is that I am getting Null for the Name and zero for the Score.

//Main

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button SaveDataButton;
    EditText TextName, TextScore;
    String Name;
    int Score;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();

                SaveDataButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
                TextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                TextScore = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                Name = TextName.getText().toString();
                Score = Integer.parseInt(TextScore.getText().toString());

            }
        });
    }


    public void SaveDataOnClick (View view){
        System.out.println(Name);
        System.out.println(Score);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

//layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.capstoneproject.module08courseproject_datastorage.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Name"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Score"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save Data"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="SaveDataOnClick" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Name and Score Data Storage"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

//output

```
11-29 22:07:01.846 3192-3192/? I/System.out: null
11-29 22:07:01.846 3192-3192/? I/System.out: 0
```

Comment: Where are you calling your `saveDataOnClick()` method?

Comment: He's using the onClick attribute in his layout to wire it to his button as an OnClickListener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing because I missed the fact that you were getting your widgets in the anonymous onClickListener wired to your FloatingActionButton.  Make these changes to fix it:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

  FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
  fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        .setAction("Action", null).show();

      // remove all the widget stuff and move it outside
    }
  });

  SaveDataButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
  TextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
  TextScore = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
  //Name = TextName.getText().toString();
  //Score = Integer.parseInt(TextScore.getText().toString());

}
```

The way you had it written is that the last 5 lines of code above are only executed if the floating action button (round button in the bottom right corner of a material design app) is clicked.  I don't think this is your intended behavior.  Instead, you want to get your widget references and keep them when `onCreate()` is called by the activity manager.

I commented out the last two lines because at this point the value in both edit texts is null.  This is useless for the name and causes a number format exception for the score (you can't convert null to a number).

Finally, I think you wan to get the actual values when the user clicks your "SAVE DATA" button, so modify your `SaveDataOnClick` method.  Remember, this method will be called each time the button is clicked/tapped, so it will get whatever the current value in the edit text fields are.  Something like this:

```
public void SaveDataOnClick (View view){
  Name = TextName.getText().toString();
  Score = Integer.parseInt(TextScore.getText().toString());
  System.out.println(Name);
  System.out.println(Score);
}
```

I made these changes, and here is my log output:

```
11-29 22:44:22.696 20997-20997/? I/System.out: bobby
11-29 22:44:22.696 20997-20997/? I/System.out: 123
```

Comment: doing this seemed to have triggered another error

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick`

Comment: Do you have any more detail in the stack trace?

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/08da2d426fec806a4337cb4d6fe200eb.png heres an image, there is a line in the stack trace saying that there is a null EditText again

Comment: Yeah, actually I just noticed something that I missed.  You are doing most of your work inside an anonymous class that you are wiring as an onClickListener to your FloatingActionButton.  That means that none of your widgets will be initialized until the floating action button is clicked once.  So your Name and Score edit texts are null when you click your other button (hence the null pointer exception when you try to pull the values out of them).

Comment: Please edit your answer to reflect this so everyone else can see it, thank you!

Comment: I just did.  Please see above.